# How to select just result value without row id and column name for function in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, dijkstra, pgrouting

I do pgRouting and I need to insert integer result to dijkstra algorithm from my `SELECT`.

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(way, 4326)) AS geometry
  FROM pgr_dijkstra(
'SELECT osm_id AS id, source, target, st_length(way) as cost FROM planet_osm_roads',
34, 3000, false
  ) as di
  JOIN planet_osm_roads pt
  ON di.edge = pt.osm_id ;
```

This is working, but if I want replace for example node 34 in dijkstra function with node number of my street with this query:

```
SELECT pl.source::integer 
FROM planet_osm_roads pl 
WHERE pl.name LIKE ''street_name'' 
LIMIT 1
```

And together:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(way, 4326)) AS geometry
  FROM pgr_dijkstra(
'SELECT osm_id AS id, source, target, st_length(way) as cost FROM planet_osm_roads',
'SELECT pl.source::integer FROM planet_osm_roads pl WHERE pl.name LIKE ''street_name'' LIMIT 1',
 3000, false
  ) as di
  JOIN planet_osm_roads pt
  ON di.edge = pt.osm_id ;
```

It will fail with error:

> ```
> ERROR:  function pgr_dijkstra(unknown, unknown, integer, boolean) is not unique
> LINE 93:   FROM pgr_dijkstra(
>                 ^
> HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

I think, it is because that my select query gives back sql result with row ID, and column name. But maybe there is another problem.

How to output it only as single integer number?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass the query as a string:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(way, 4326)) AS geometry
FROM pgr_dijkstra(
  'SELECT osm_id AS id, source, target, st_length(way) as cost FROM planet_osm_roads',
  (SELECT pl.source::integer FROM planet_osm_roads pl WHERE pl.name LIKE 'street_name' LIMIT 1),
   3000, false
) as di
  JOIN planet_osm_roads pt
  ON di.edge = pt.osm_id;
```

Or alternatively use a derived table

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(way, 4326)) AS geometry
FROM (
  SELECT pl.source::integer as source
  FROM planet_osm_roads pl 
  WHERE pl.name 
  LIKE 'street_name' LIMIT 1
) pl 
  join lateral pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT osm_id AS id, source, target, st_length(way) as cost FROM planet_osm_roads',
    pl.source,
    3000, false
  ) as di on true
  JOIN planet_osm_roads pt ON di.edge = pt.osm_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Vertex is integer argument and you were trying to put text there.
Just change ' to ()

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(way, 4326)) AS geometry
  FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT osm_id AS id, source, target, st_length(way) as cost FROM planet_osm_roads',
(SELECT pl.source::integer FROM planet_osm_roads pl WHERE pl.name LIKE ''street_name'' LIMIT 1),
 3000, false
  ) as di
  JOIN planet_osm_roads pt
  ON di.edge = pt.osm_id ;
```

It is one way , the other is to write function with street name as and in argument and your geojson as an output.